# Using :row-fn failing in clojure.jdbc query call

Tags: jdbc, clojure

This code works, printing the rows in the given table:

```
(defn count-extreferences-subset [config]
  (let [emr-dbs (:emr-databases config)]
    (println "Counting external references: " emr-dbs)
    (jdbc/with-db-connection [dbconn (:db-spec (first emr-dbs))]
                             (let [q "SELECT * FROM LOCREG"
                                    rs (jdbc/query dbconn [q])]
                               (dorun (map println rs))))))
```

According to the documentation in clojure.jdbc, this should also work, but should print the rows as the result set is realized (preventing memory overflow for large result sets):

```
(defn count-extreferences-subset [config]
  (let [emr-dbs (:emr-databases config)]
    (println "Counting external references: " emr-dbs)
    (jdbc/with-db-connection [dbconn (:db-spec (first emr-dbs))]
                             (let [q "SELECT * FROM LOCREG"
                                   _ (jdbc/query dbconn [q] {:row-fn println})]))))
```

However this fails at run-time with the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: {:row-fn #object[clojure.core$println 0x46ed7a0e "clojure.core$println@46ed7a0e"]}
```

Any idea why the use of the :row-fn option is failing?

Comment: This seems to be the right approach in the current clojure.java.jdbc version. The query fn has an arity of 3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the curly braces are the problem. Your code should follow the following pattern:

```
(jdbc/query db-spec 
  ["select name, cost from fruit where cost = 12"]
  :row-fn add-tax)
```

You can fine more information [in The Clojure Cookbook](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/06_databases/6-03_manipulating-an-SQL-database.asciidoc).  I highly recommend buying a copy!